# Workflow manager registration problems

Tags: workflow

I am configuring a Workflow manager client on my SP server 2013, but when I want to register it, I get the following error: 
There is a red line text with this content:
 Register-SPWorkflowService : The remote server returned an error: (401)
 Found.[image]
Can you please tell me how can I resolve this error.
The error has been uploaded on this post, called register.png.

Answer (score 0):

The Powershell Cmdlet you are running is wrong.
The parameter should be `-SPSite` . Please remove the _ from the cmdlet

Comment: I corrected it, but the problem has not been resolved.

Comment: Can you provide what is the error you get now ?